# Pivot with cross and union CTE in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
   (SELECT  
        tblLandAreas.LandAreaId, Sysproperties.Name, 
        tblLandAreaPropertyValues.Value 
    FROM tbllandareas
    LEFT JOIN tblLandAreaProperties ON tblLandAreaProperties.LandAreaId = tblLandAreas.LandAreaId
    LEFT JOIN tblLandAreaPropertyValues ON tblLandAreaProperties.LandAreaPropertyId = tblLandAreaPropertyValues.LandAreaPropertyId
    CROSS JOIN Sysproperties SysProperties 
    WHERE 
        SysProperties.SysPropertyId = tblLandAreaProperties.SysPropertyId 
        AND tblLandAreas.LandAreaId = '1175' 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DISTINCT 
        (tblLandAreas.LandAreaId), Sysproperties.Name, null 
    FROM tbllandareas
    LEFT JOIN tblLandAreaProperties ON tblLandAreaProperties.LandAreaId = tblLandAreas.LandAreaId
    LEFT JOIN tblLandAreaPropertyValues ON tblLandAreaProperties.LandAreaPropertyId = tblLandAreaPropertyValues.LandAreaPropertyId
    CROSS JOIN Sysproperties SysProperties  
    WHERE tblLandAreas.LandAreaId = '1175') AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    MAX(SourceTable.Value)
    FOR SourceTable.Name IN (SELECT Name FROM Sysproperties) 
) AS PivotTable
```

and I'm getting this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't use `SELECT Name FROM Sysproperties` in your PIVOT function like that. If you are going to have unknown values, then you need to use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a static list inside your for clause of pivot or you can use a dynamic list as shown below

```
DECLARE @col NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @col=   STUFF(( select distinct ',[' +   Name +']'FROM Sysproperties for XML path ('')),1,1,'')

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)


SET @query = '
SELECT * 
FROM 
(SELECT  
    tblLandAreas.LandAreaId, Sysproperties.Name, 
    tblLandAreaPropertyValues.Value 
FROM tbllandareas
LEFT JOIN tblLandAreaProperties ON tblLandAreaProperties.LandAreaId = tblLandAreas.LandAreaId
LEFT JOIN tblLandAreaPropertyValues ON tblLandAreaProperties.LandAreaPropertyId = tblLandAreaPropertyValues.LandAreaPropertyId
CROSS JOIN Sysproperties SysProperties 
WHERE 
    SysProperties.SysPropertyId = tblLandAreaProperties.SysPropertyId 
    AND tblLandAreas.LandAreaId = ''1175'' 

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT 
    (tblLandAreas.LandAreaId), Sysproperties.Name, null 
FROM tbllandareas
LEFT JOIN tblLandAreaProperties ON tblLandAreaProperties.LandAreaId = tblLandAreas.LandAreaId
LEFT JOIN tblLandAreaPropertyValues ON tblLandAreaProperties.LandAreaPropertyId = tblLandAreaPropertyValues.LandAreaPropertyId
CROSS JOIN Sysproperties SysProperties  
WHERE tblLandAreas.LandAreaId = ''1175'') AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
MAX(SourceTable.Value)
FOR SourceTable.Name IN (' + @col + ')
) AS PivotTable'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```